# Data is not cleared inspite of apc_add() TTL parameter

Tags: php, apc, command-line-interface

Why `key_1` is not cleared when execution time is greater than `TTL`?

```
$ttl = 3;

$key = 'key_1';

if (apc_exists($key)) {
    echo "Data exists!\n";
    if (apc_delete($key))
        echo "Data deleted.\n";
    else
        die("Unable to delete data\n");
} else {
    echo "Data not present.\n";
}

apc_add($key, 'some-value', $ttl);

$start = microtime(true);

echo "TTL: ".$ttl."sec\n";

while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    $exec_time = round(microtime(true) - $start, 1);
    $data = apc_fetch($key);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo 'key_1: ['.$data.']: '
            .$exec_time."sec"
            .(($exec_time > $ttl) ? "\t<<< Data still exists!\n" : "\n");
    } else {
        die("Data was cleared!\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also var_dump the response of `apc_add`? Is it possible that `key_1` already exists with a longer TTL?

Comment: I have edited the script to check if data is already present and it was not there...

Answer (score 0):

I read [the docs](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.apc-add.php) a little more and I found the answer. Under the section for the TTL parameter:

> Time To Live; store var in the cache for ttl seconds. After the ttl has passed, the stored variable will be expunged from the cache (on the next request). If no ttl is supplied (or if the ttl is 0), the value will persist until it is removed from the cache manually, or otherwise fails to exist in the cache (clear, restart, etc.).

The key part is the first set of brackets; **(on the next request)**

Comment: Well, there's no request as it is cli. See tags :)

Comment: Similar sort of deal as I understand. Try running a script to store a value, then manually try to fetch the value 3 seconds later with a seperate CLI call.

Comment: Tried that already - the data is not shared among the processes though

Comment: Do you have the CLI mode turned on? `apc.enable_cli` - http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.enable-cli